# Joint pdf of random variable and its function

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Let be X an absolutely continuous random variable and Y=g(X) a second random variable (g is a Borel function $g:R\rightarrow R$). What’s the joint probability density function of the random vector (X,Y)?

Comment: For rectangles is this: $\mathbf{P}((X,Y) \in \mathrm{A} \times \mathrm{B}) = \mathbf{P}(X \in \mathrm{A} \cap g^{-1}(\mathrm{B})).$ Can you generalise it to other Borel sets?

Comment: I’m looking for the probability density function, not for the probability itself.

Comment: In that case, it's zero.

Comment: Think of the case of $g$ being the identity function and say that $X$ is standard normal. The distribution of $(X,X)$ is degenerated (you probably know this already). I don't have a proof on top of my head but I am pretty sure that the density of a random vector $(X, g(X))$ cannot exist.